Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку html в переменную на JavaScript добавилось +1?
Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, которую я сделала на HTML, в переменную на JavaScript добавилось +1.

Приведите пример кода.

Этот вопрос похож на: Считаем при нажатии на кнопку; как изменить значение переменной в js по нажатию кнопки на странице. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.



var count = 0;

function add() {
  count++;
  alert(count);
}
<button onclick="add()">Добавить 1</button>    




Можно еще скрестить с этим и будет вывод переменной в html

@SwaD Этого не требуется в вопросе (и там нет моего ответа).

Тот комментарий был для автора вопроса и для будущих поколений

@SwaD Используйте @имя для отправки коментов конкретному юзеру

Совсем необязательно всегда вписывать в тело атрибута onclick вызов функции, здесь просто пишется код. В данном случае x++ достаточно и никакой специальной функции в отдельном скрипте. console.log добавлен для наглядности.


let x=0;
<button type="button" onclick="x++; console.log(x)">click me</button>




В onclick пишется функция, обработчик события нажатия кнопки, и если она не указана явно, то она создаётся автоматически. Поэтому ваш код мало чем отличается от моего ответа.

В onclick пишется script.

@RomanC, раз уж пошла такая пьянка, формально туда можно и ссылку(скриптлет) воткнуть: <button type="button" onclick="javascript:x++; console.log(x)">click me</button>.  эмм... мож конкурс объявить? ну... чтоб было ради чего происходить, всему тому, что тут собственно уже и происходит :3 учитывая тип кнопки, конкурс обещает быть интересным :D

@puffleek, это мне? Я виноват в том, что ответил на вопрос или что? Что заинтересовался проблемой автора вопроса? Или что? Тип кнопки указан верно и по всем правилам. И задолбали везде писать во всех справочниках, что там функция передается, а круглые скобки при этом никто упорно не замечает. Это ВЫЗОВ функции без параметров - просто кусок кода. Это архаичный атрибут, ничего общего с HTMLElement.onclick в js не имеет. Вот к этому и ответ. onclick="x++" (при x - та самая переменная из вопроса) - что может быть проще...)

@puffleeck Нет, ссылку - нельзя, тип атрибута не подходящий. Тип кнопки можно убрать, т.к. он берется по умолчанию. Вставлять код в атрибуте можно, но если его не много, но что при этом происходит уже не представляет интереса. Если сделать несколько шагов назад, и вспомнить из чего, собственно состоит HTML, то можно понять как события прикрепляются к элементам, что даёт нам возможность отвечать на всякие действия пользователя.

@Leonid, это мне? ну нет, к тебе если и есть замечание, то только одно - type='button' для этого тега лишний(ему место в <input>, а <button> и так кнопка хоть давай ему тип хоть нет). но вот некий другой оппонент... просто глянь вообще все каменты здесь(и к вопросу и к ответам), у тебя нет ощущения будто кто-то прям старается утереть всем нос?))) я то не против активности, а очень даже за, но тут... только вдумайся - утереть всем нос в прибавлении единички в переменную... на что и намекнул вопросом про конкурс :3

@RomanC, код с протокольной приставкой onclick=' javascript: x++;...' так же называемый скриптлетом, является ссылкой по определению, так что нет - ссылку точно можно, иначе эти скриптлеты не работали бы.

@puffleeck Ну и зачем в onclick вставлять ссылку, если там ее быть не должно? Если сделать кнопку как анкор, то можно было бы туда вставить скриптлет.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904199/whats-the-point-of-button-type-button
